# Not able to create temp table in stored procedure in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a temp table in Oracle.

I had done it in SQL Server like this:

```
IF object_id('tempdb..#qcCSTemp') IS NOT NULL   
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #qcCSTemp
END
```

I want something similar in Oracle. I tried this code:

```
create global temporary table temptable (mgr number);
```

but I get an error:

> Error(32,7): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE" when expecting one     of the following:     ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod    null pragma raise return select update while with          << continue close current delete fetch lock    insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall    merge pipe purge

Please advice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add some more code of yours for a better understanding?

Comment: **(1)** Find the manuals for Oracle (physical or online), **(2)** look up the exact syntax for `CREATE TABLE`, and **(3)** use that syntax .....

Comment: Temporary tables in Oracle are very different from temporary tables in SQL Server.  Temporary tables in Oracle are global temporary tables-- the definition is visible to all sessions only the data is local to the session-- as opposed to local temporary tables in SQL Server where the definition is visible only to the session.  In Oracle, if you need a temporary table, which is rare, it would be created once at the same time that you create all your other permanent tables.  It wouldn't be created and dropped at runtime.

Comment: I second what Justin has said; moreover, what are you using the temporary table for? As Justin says, it's rare that you need a temporary table, and it's entirely possible that you can do whatever it is you're doing in one query without having to break it up into separate bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
begin
      create global temporary table temptable (mgr number);
    end;
    /
```

ORA-06550: line 2, column 3:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE" when expecting one of the following:

( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma
   raise return select update while with 
     <<
   continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
   savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge

```
    begin
      execute immediate 'create global temporary table temptable (mgr number)';
   execute immediate 'insert into   temptable select pct_free from dba_tables';
   execute immediate 'insert into   temptable  values(-99)'; 
    end;
    /
```

4  /
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed

```
select count(*) from temptable;

     0
```

Comment: thanks, for reply. But the table is not identified by the below sripts.        Also,how do i insert data to temptable from another table.